# Script to automate timeshift backup and azuracast update

Tags: docker, scripting

I’m running an Azuracast docker instance on Linode and want to try to find a way to automate my updates. Right now my routine is when I notice there are updates by accessing the Azuracast web panel, I usually run timeshift to create a backup using the following command

timeshift —-create —-comment “azuracast update ”

And then I use the following to update azuracast

cd /var/azuracast/
./docker.sh update-self
./docker.sh update

Then it asks me to ensure the azuracast installation is backed up before updating, to which i would usually just press enter.

After that is completed, it asks me if i want to clean up all stopped docker containers and images to save space, which i usually say no to.

What I’m wondering is if there is a way to create a bash script, or python or something to automate all of this, and then have it run on a schedule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can write a shell script to execute these commands and then run it on a schedule using [crontab(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html).

For example your script might look like:

```
#! /bin/sh

# Backup azuracast and restart docker container
timeshift --create --comment “azuracast update” && \
    cd /var/azuracast/ && \
    ./docker.sh update-self && \
    (yes | ./docker.sh update)
```

It sounds like this `docker.sh` program takes some user inputs.  See if there are options you can pass to it that will allow you to run it non-interactively. *(Seems there isn't, see edit.)*

To setup your cron job, you can put the script in `/etc/cron.hourly`, `/etc/cron.daily`, `/etc/cron.weekly`, or `/etc/cron.monthly`.  Or if you need more control, you can get started configuring a cron job with `crontab -e`.  [Better explanation](https://askubuntu.com/a/2369/1188264).

**EDIT**:  Assuming [this is the script](https://github.com/AzuraCast/AzuraCast/blob/main/docker.sh#L117) you're using, it doesn't seem to have a way to run `update` non-interactively.  Fear not though, there's a program for this: [yes(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/yes.1.html).  This will answer yes to both of the questions, but honestly running `docker system prune -f` is probably a good idea.  If you really want to answer no to that, you could probably substitute `yes` for `printf "y\nn"` to answer yes to the first and no to the second.

Also note that there's at [least one other](https://github.com/AzuraCast/AzuraCast/blob/main/docker.sh#L374) y/n question it could ask you, which you probably want to answer yes to.

Comment: Awesome mate. Appreciate your help. Ran the script you came up with and it worked absolutely perfectly. Now I can make sure my server stays 100% up to date